# How can I display and log PHP errors on IIS7?

Tags: php, iis-7, log-files

We're running PHP 5.2.5 on an IIS 7 Server and we're having problems making PHP errors visible... At the moment whenever we have a PHP error the server sends back a 500 error with the message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

This might be a good setting for production websites but it's rather annoying on a development server... ;-)

I have tried configuring `php.ini` to display errors to the screen as well as log them to a specific folder but it seems that the Server catches all errors before and prevents and handling by PHP...

Does someone know what we have to do to make IIS display PHP errors on screen? Any links, tipps or tutorials on the subject would be appreciated!

Comment: First, ensure that you have these: `log_errors=1`, `error_reporting=-1`, `log_errors_max_len=0`.

Comment: `ini_set("display_errors", "on");` add these lines in php file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just to double check, do you have logging set to `error_reporting = E_ALL`, and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini`? Usually this is enough to display these errors in IIS 7.

Next, take a look at your IIS settings, as it may be set to only show error messages locally. In the IIS 7 configuration editor this is under system.webServer->httpErrors. You will need to change errorMode to Detailed from DetailedLocalOnly. Obviously this now means anyone browsing your site will be able to see the error.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to keep them local you can use Remote Desktop to log in to the server and run the app from there, if you can.

Comment: Yes I checked and that's all configured properly.

Comment: Added some more troubleshooting info

Comment: Changing the errorMode to "Detailed" from "DetailedLocalOnly" did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to disable display_errors after you are done :-)

Comment: I had to remove the collection of HTTP errors under system.webServer as well. Didn't work with PHP until I did.

Comment: Please highlight that `system.webServer` with my blood and add note: "Yes, there is combo".

Comment: where will the PHP errors be logged if this is configured?

Comment: Edge-case, but in the case of Wordpress, navigating the backend (i.e. logged in pages) would cause the blank 500 page, whereas hitting e.g. the frontpage (not logged in) with `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled showed the error and source (file + line-no.)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add, that "existingResponse" should be set to "PassThrough". I didn't get any real error messages without that additional setting.

Comment: Where is located this setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using the IIS Manager GUI. Select your Site and double-click Error Pages. Then hit 'Edit Feature Settings...' and select the 'detailed errors' option instead of the default 'detail errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests'. Voilà, simple as that!

Comment: Where can the logs and errors be shown then?

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into the settings on the webserver into php configuration and there is a setting in there for error reporting and is set to production by default.  Had to change it to development even after changing the php.ini and the suggestion here.  I am using iis 7.5 on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these and it did not work.  Specifically "Configuration editor" I needed to keep "existing Response" to "auto".

However I found that if you use FastCGI you need to go into IIS manager -> default web site -> FastCGI->
then select `c:\php\php-cgi-.exe` and "edit..".

Under "Standard error mode" you need to change `ReturnGeneric500` to `ReturnStdErrIn500`

This will display the PHP errors if you have them turned on in PHP.INI or through settings in PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me on a shared hosting platform, without access to IIS manager, you can also edit the web.config file and manually add to the system.webServer element:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

Afterwards I used my host control panel to recycle application pool.