# IIS 7 not reporting PHP errors?

Tags: php, iis-7

When I encounter an error in a PHP site running on my local IIS7 error, I just get a blank page. I have tried disabling the "Show friendly HTTP errors" option in IE.

In my PHP.ini, the display_errors = On is enabled. In my script, I have the following set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

I'm not sure why IIS is still not showing the errors? Is there anything I'm missing?

Edit: To be clear, I DO know there is an error. IIS7 is just not displaying the error, and seems to be suppressing it. I even tried enabling "PassThrough" errors via the command line for this site, but that didn't help either.

Comment: isit showing any other kind of errors?

Comment: No, the page is completely blank

Comment: try to purposely add a syntax error or a Fatal by calling an undefined function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this way:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The display_errors is boolean value, i think it can not set to 'On'.

Other thing is to install PHP Manager for IIS and then configure error reporting with this plugin, set it to development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried something like apache? It was built specifically to run something like PHP and it configures way easier. Thats one thing I see with AGILE web development. Most of the time you do not have the luxury time to setup and config your tools it just has to run of the bat.

http://www.apache.org/

I also fount this on serverfault : [How can I display and log PHP errors on IIS7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7)

Maybe your question is better based there? Also this might be of help :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151937/impossible-to-show-errors-with-php-under-iis7-5

I hope I helped you with finding your error.

Comment: Hey, I did eventually set up XAMPP, which solves my problem. However, I'd like to leave this question open, in case somebody else has the same problem. I will check out the ServerFault thread, and see if that helps.