# Detailed error from IIS 6 & PHP instead of 500 Internal server fault

Tags: php, iis-6, 500-error

I am currently trying to debug my PHP application on a IIS 6 server. As soon as I make an error in the PHP code I get a "500 - Internal server error" page.

I have understood that the default way to show an error is to localhost only and that it is possible to change this behavior by changing the error mode from "DetailedLocalOnly" to "Detailed".

The problem I am facing now is to understand how to do this on IIS 6, I have found a lot of guides for IIS 7 only.

I did find the MetaBase.xml, but I have no idea how the syntax should be in there.

[Serverfault question with different answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/382511/iis-not-displaying-detailed-php-errors-shows-server-fault-500-instead)

[IIS 6 MetaBase](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a0ea8e51-fb2a-4e80-9d5a-7fe3ae246570.mspx?mfr=true)

[IIS 7 Config reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors)

[Serverfault question for IIS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7)

I appreciate any help you can give me.