# How can I enable error logging and where are the errors logs for IIS 8?

Tags: php, iis, http, logging

I would like to capture php errors and http errors. I've enabled error logging in PHP, but I do not see where in IIS 8 I can enable errors.

Is this possible to do?

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Its very similar to IIS7.5: http://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7

Comment: @dirt thankyou, how do i get to this: system.webServer->httpErrors

Comment: @dirt similar but entirely different