# How can I display and log PHP errors on IIS7.5?

Tags: php, iis

I running PHP 5.4.5 on an IIS 7.5 Server (under Win7 64) and i have problems making PHP errors visible.
At the moment whenever i have a PHP error the server sends back a 500 error with the message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

I use phpmanager to configure php. The php Ini is correct with errorlogging E_ALL and display_errors enabled (error is writen to log also).
I already set the errorMode to Detailed from DetailedLocalOnly and removed all errorpages as well. But it is stil the same Error 500...
PS: I read already all posting on serverfault and stackoverflow.

Comment: you can submit an answer to your question and mark it as answered. this will help others that come here looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [How can I display and log PHP errors on IIS7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7) . You will need to edit http configuration so it allows displaying of errors to remote users.

Comment: thx, I read this post and tried it already. But it doesn't help.

Answer (score -2):

An error 500 is an internal server error, not an error with PHP. It indicates something wrong with your Web Server, maybe an IIS mis-configuration. Check your Web Server logs for the specific issue.

Comment: the errorlog (php) says 
'PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function FetchRow() on a non-object in D:\inetpub\htdocs\tematres\common\include\fun.sql.php on line 2885' and ISS say at the same time 'GET /tematres/vocab/index.php - 80 - 192.168.178.12 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0 500 0 0 442'

Comment: explained here: [link]http://www.geekmungus.co.uk/microsoft-windows/enablingiis75andphperrorsonwindows2008serverr2[link]

Answer (score -3):

i'm developer of Tematres, may be this thread can help you: http://sourceforge.net/p/tematres/discussion/592732/thread/e2ed8799/?limit=50#d22e

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This post will be removed if not improved. Thank you!